# In Material UI I want to thicken the lines of my drawer, how would I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui

I'm working on having a left-side navigation bar for a web app I'm working on. The issue I'm running into is I want to make some style changes and I find it difficult to do so with the Drawer component. The biggest is I want the actual line of the drawer to be thicker if that makes sense.

Code below:

```
function SideNav({drawerWidth = 170}) { const history = useHistory(); const dispatch = useDispatch(); 


return(

  <Drawer
    PaperProps={{ padding: '20px'}}
    sx={{
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
        width: drawerWidth,
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
      },
      
    }}
    variant="permanent"
    anchor="left"
  >

   

    <List>
        <ListItem >
        <img class="rotate" src="record1.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <Button  variant='outlined' onClick={() => history.push('/home')}> Home </Button>
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem >
        <img class="rotate" src="record1.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <Button  variant='outlined' onClick={() => history.push('/create')}>Create</Button>
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem>
        <img class="rotate" src="scratch.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <Button  variant='outlined'   onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })}>Log out </Button>
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem>
        <img class="rotate" src="scratch.png" width="80" height="80" onClick={() => history.push('/profile')}/>
        <Button  variant='outlined'   onClick={() => history.push('/create')}>Profile </Button>
        </ListItem>

        </List>

    <Divider />


  </Drawer>
  );

}

export default SideNav;`
```

I've fiddled around with the sx={{}} and have yet to find a solution to the issue. My goal is just to make the drawer/navigation a little more defined so it pops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to the right border of the drawer. If it is the case you should change the prop PaperProps to:

```
PaperProps={{ sx: { borderRightWidth: 2, padding: '20px' } }}
```

Let me know if this works for you